# Two Resteasy-based WARs, one doesn't scan for Providers?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jackson, resteasy

I have 2 m2e-managed projects in Eclipse targeting Tomcat 7. Each have identical configurations, except for artifactId in the POM and display-name in the web.xml (the bulk of the configuration from one was cut/paste from the other).

On the first one, when I "run on server", all Resteasy classes are registered, and @Providers are scanned for and regiestered.

On the other, the web servers are registered, but there's no evidence that the scan is happening.  Has anyone run into a situation like this?  I'm dying to know what's different about these two projects.

Working logs:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/itworks] has started
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned @Provider: xxx.BadRequestHandler
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned @Provider: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned @Provider: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned @Provider: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned @Provider: org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned resource: xxx.Hashmask
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned resource: xxx.HelloWorld
Feb 12, 2013 12:48:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/itworks] is completed
```

Nonworking logs:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/noworkie] has started
Feb 12, 2013 12:56:30 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned resource: yyy.HelloWorld
Feb 12, 2013 12:56:30 PM org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap 
INFO: Adding scanned resource: yyy.MongoTest
Feb 12, 2013 12:56:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/noworkie] is completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this param to web.xml of your projects:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.use.deployment.sensitive.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It helped me with similar problem on Jboss. I found this solution in [resteasy jira issue.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-748?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)
Looks like it's known issue in resteasy...

Comment: I've moved on to different prototypes now, so this question isn't so relevant to me anymore.  I'm going to accept your answer, as it seems plausible. :)